# Resize GraphicsMagick image in memory

Tags: node.js, image, memory, graphicsmagick

I want to resize an image in memory using GraphicsMagick, using the `gm` package for Node.js.

I tried:

```
const gm = require("gm");

gm("octocat.jpg").resize(240, 240).size(function (err, data) {
    console.log(err || data);
    // => { width: 896, height: 896 }
});
```

I suppose that `gm` stores the initial file data in memory and prepares the options to run the `gm` process.

But how I can resize the object in memory and get the new buffer (`.toPNGBuffer`) and size for the resized image?

Comment: You already know the new size from the resize, no?

Comment: Actually good point... Turns out that `toBuffer("PNG", fn)` returns the resized image buffer—which is just perfect. I can use it later to create a new image: `gm(pngBuffer).size(...)` will return the resized image size. You can post an answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use node-canvas: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

```
node-canvas extends the canvas API to provide interfacing with node,
for example streaming PNG data, converting to a Buffer instance, etc.
```

Example:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/images/squid.png', function(err, squid){
  if (err) throw err;
  img = new Image;
  img.src = squid;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);
});
```

Also, Canvas is *3 times faster* than ImageMagic.

You can try to compare Node.js modules for images manipulation - https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

```
author's results:
  canvas.js : 4.001 img/sec;
  gm-imagemagic.js : 1.206 img/sec;
  gm.js : 1.536 img/sec;
  lwip.js : 0.406 img/sec;
```